# How to use gke-gcloud-auth-plugin with a gcloud service account key file?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, gcloud, kubectl

In CI, with gcp auth plugin I was using gcloud auth activate-service-account ***@developer.gserviceaccount.com --key-file ***.json prior to execute kubectl commands.
Now with gke-gcloud-auth-plugin I can’t find any equivalent to use a gcp service account key file.
I've installed `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` and `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version` is giving me `Kubernetes v1.25.2-alpha+ae91c1fc0c443c464a4c878ffa2a4544483c6d1f`
Would you know if there’s a way?

I tried to add this command:
`kubectl config set-credentials my-user --auth-provider=gcp`
But I still get:

```
error: The gcp auth plugin has been removed. Please use the "gke-gcloud-auth-plugin" kubectl/client-go credential plugin instead.
```

Answer (score 21):

You will need to set the env variable to use the new plugin before doing the `get-credentials`:

```bash
export USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $CLUSTER \
  --region $REGION \
  --project $PROJECT \
  --internal-ip
```

I would not have expected the env variable to still be required (now that the gcp auth plugin is completely deprecated) - but it seems it still is.

Your kubeconfig will end up looking like this if the new auth provider is in use.

```yaml
...
- name: $NAME
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      command: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
      installHint: Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following
        https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
      provideClusterInfo: true
```

Comment: Was running into the same issue, tried this answer - and it worked. I'm as surprised as you are about still needing the environment variable.